# rails 4 routing with edit fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following link

```
<%= link_to 'Update Profile', controller: :customers, action: :edit, id: session[:customer_id] %>
```

Which will generate url

```
http://localhost:3000/customers/17/edit
```

But when I modify my route as

```
get 'edit_customer' => 'customers#edit'
```

And my link is like this

```
<li><%= link_to 'Update Profile', edit_customer_path(session[:customer]) %></li>
```

The url generated is

```
http://localhost:3000/customers//edit
```

How to correct this one

Answer (score 0):

change: `edit_customer_path(session[:customer])`

to: `edit_customer_path(session[:customer.id])`

Comment: I hope session[:customer] holds customer id